# what is the cardinal number of these sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm not sure about **2**, and I really don't know how to begin **3**, any ideas?.

$\mathbb R^+=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x>0\}$.

1. $K=\{x\in\mathbb R^+\mid x^2\in\mathbb N\}$
2. $L=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^+\times\mathbb R^+\mid x\cdot y\in\mathbb N\}$
3. $M=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^+\times\mathbb R^+\mid (x\cdot y\in\mathbb N)\text{ and }(x^2\in\mathbb N)\}$

---

1. I proved the one to one and onto function from $\mathbb N-\{0\}$ to $K$. $f(x)=\sqrt x$. so it's countable ($\aleph_0$).
2. I showed that $L\subseteq\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\rightarrow|L| \leq |\mathbb R\times\mathbb R|=\mathfrak c$. And the one to one function $f:\mathbb R^+\rightarrow L$, $f(x)=(x,1/x)$, $\implies \mathfrak c=|\mathbb R^+|\leq |L|\implies |L|=\mathfrak c$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about (2).

About (3) note that there are only countably many $x$'s that you can choose from. And use that to show that there can only be countably many $y$'s for each such $x$.

Comment: thanks, I ended up showing a one to one function from M to$N^*XN^*$

Comment: You should take a look at the edits that I made to your answer. In particular how to make a $\times$ symbol (and how to write $\{$ too).

Comment: I will Asaf and thank you I was struggling doing it... also I think you answered my previous questions also, thanks!

Comment: [That's not surprising](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/elementary-set-theory/topusers); and you're welcome.